# wp_nav_menu exclude pages from menu doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to exclude pages from my menu in WP. For sure the id of desired page is 21, but it's not working

```
if ( has_nav_menu( 'header-menu' ) ) {
    wp_nav_menu( array( 
    'theme_location' => 'header-menu',
    'exclude' => '21',
    'container' => 'div',
    'container_class' => 'header-content',
    'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav',
) );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of code to exclude menu item from header-menu

```
function custom_exclude_menu_items( $items, $menu, $args ) {
    if( $args->theme_location == 'header-menu' ){
        foreach ( $items as $key => $item ) {
            if ( $item->object_id == 21 ) unset( $items[$key] );
        }
    }
    return $items;
}

add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_items', 'custom_exclude_menu_items', null, 3 );
```

Try this ,then let me know the result.
Thanks

Comment: Is there a way to filter the post or page that is being currently shown?